# Нужна помощь с задачей С#

Tags: c#

> Дана строка. Словом текста является последовательность цифр и букв латинского
> алфавита; между соседними словами - не менее одного пробела, за последним словом -
> точка. Найти и сохранить в строке те слова, в которых цифры и буквы латинского
> алфавита чередуются. Все остальные слова удалить.

Comment: Уважаемый, поймите одну простую вещь: Вы на SO, сайте, где люди собирают совместными силами интересные, полезные вопросы и соответственно ответы на них. Это не фриланс биржа, не бюро решения задач. Какую вот ваш вопрос имеет ценность для будущих читателей? Почему мы должны тратить свое время на то, что вы не соизволили даже оформить по-человечески? Добавляйте свои попытки решения, показывайте, что именно у вас не получилось и тогда да, это будет уместным для SO вопросом, ну а сейчас, тут его даже нету, а есть банальное "ей, решите за меня!".

Comment: Ну,для меня на этом сайте сидят опытные люди,я только начал изучения языка, поэтому прошу помошь,я не прошу "решить за меня",просто задать направление  ,этому я уже буду очень благодарен)

Comment: `поэтому прошу помошь,я не прошу "решить за меня"` - а где у вас хоть один знак вопроса? Где сам вопрос-то? Я вижу задачу, которую вам надо решить, да, ок, но это ведь не вопрос, это ТЗ для вас, вот и делайте, а уже когда будет **вопрос**, и вы **не смогли его решить сами**, тогда приходите сюда, с вашими наработками, поможем без каких-либо проблем. Сейчас вы как минимум нарушаете правила ресурса, а как максимум, плюете в лицо тем самым "опытным людям". И ведь это 2-й вопрос, где вам также сказали "покажите ваши попытки", вы показали, ок, но здесь то что? В следующий раз я вам поставлю минус.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вводим строку
2. Проходим по всем символам:
   **Если** (символ i - цифра И символ i+1 - цифра ИЛИ символ i - буква И символ i+1 - буква, то
   *удаляем нынешнее слово*

   **Если** символ i - пробел, то
   *обнуляем нынешнее слово*

   **Иначе** 
    *добавляем символ i к нынешнему слову*

Большего вам, увы, никто не даст, пока вы не сделаете что-то сами.

> Предупреждение: Если в ближайшее время вы не сделаете правки вопроса, добавив собственные попытки решения, то ваш вопрос в это самое ближайшее время закроют.

Comment: Если мой ответ был вам полезен, пожалуйста, отметьте его как принятый, нажав галочку.